# Using multiple 4N25 optocouplers - Approach for compact PCB design?

Tags: arduino, pcb, opto-isolator

I'm working on building an Ardunio Nano device that detects if automotive 12V circuits are on / off. I was able to successfully build & test a [sample circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73857/detect-car-12v-using-arduino/73899#73899) provided Phil Frost.

The question I have is around saving space. I'm using this in a motorcycle so space is at a premium. The 4N25 uses 6-pins, even though I only use 4. I'm monitoring 6 separate 12V circuits and I'm wondering how to make it more compact.

Is there another chip (maybe a multi-optocoupler) or approach that will help me save PCB real estate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are quad optoisolators (one 16-pin package, either surface-mount (0.1" or 0.05" pitch) or old-fashioned DIP).

[image]

Just go to your favorite parametric search engine, such as Digikey's and select 4 channel optoisolator.

Product Index>Isolators>Optoisolators - Transistor, Photovoltaic Output

Around 150 choices with different packages, CTRs, voltage ratings etc.